# Onsen-Ui with JQuery, Disable all page animations

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, onsen-ui

I am a relative newcomer to using the Onsen-UI framework after becoming a dinosaur using JQuery Mobile.  Somethings I have found straight forward but a few things have stumped me.

I'am stuck trying to find a way of turning off globally the animations when moving to a new page. Currently I am setting the attribute *animations:none* on each push-page event with code shown below:

```js
navigator.pushPage('tabFootball.html', { animation: 'none' });
```

Is there a way to set this globally?  In JQM I could just use this piece of code:

```js
$(document).bind('pageinit', function(){
  $.mobile.defaultPageTransition = "none";
};
```

The documentation doesn't seem to show a way to achieve this and searching the internet looks fruitless.